# How to add an item to the Applications menu?

Tags: centos, gnome

How can I add an application to *Applications > Internet* in Gnome Desktop running on CentOS 6.4?

Per this [old Docs link](http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhd-dg-en-4/ch-ddg-menus.html), it suggests to edit `/etc/xdg/menus/applications.menu`.

How can I add `/home/danny/some/path/myprog/prog` (executable) to my Gnome Applications menu?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
vi /usr/share/applications/newitem.desktop
```

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=My Program
Exec=/home/danny/some/path/myprog/prog
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.15
```

An icon can be added by including `Icon=/some/path`.

Comment: Since this is an application in the 'danny' account, you could put it in ~danny/.local/share/applications/newitem.desktop, which will only show up in the 'danny' user's menus.

Comment: Is it possible to put run as sudo(root) option ?

Comment: any source or docs that describe what each field means?

Comment: If your path contains white spaces, enclose it in quotes.

Comment: I removed Version, Terminal, Type, StartupNotify and X-Desktop-File-Install-Version (left only header, Name, Exec, Categories and Icon). I don't see it causing any trouble.

Comment: @spy for posterity, here's the section of the `.desktop` file spec listing the recognized desktop entry keys: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys

Answer (score 13):

There is another solution by enabling an **edit menu** option.

You can have this menu by installing the `alacarte` package with this command (as root):

```
yum install alacarte
```

After that, just restart your X server and you can edit your menus with a mouse right click on the toolbar.